# Rolling back an alembic merge

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, alembic

I checked out an existing Flask-Restful project that uses Alembic and, when I ran the migrations, I had to merge different alembic heads. I can't work out how this happened - I'd pushed from my desktop and pulled straight down to my laptop.

I did manage to resolve the issue and carried on as normal.

Later on, I pushed to Git and pulled the project back down on to my desktop machine. When I try to run

```
python manage.py db upgrade
```

I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "logo" of relation "despatch_details" does not exist
[SQL: 'ALTER TABLE despatch_details DROP COLUMN logo']
```

Looking at the database on my desktop machine, I can see that it's ahead of the merge point. For example, some tables that the post-merge scripts attempt to create already exist on my desktop box and the `alembic_version` is midway between the merge point and the latest migration.

I've tried manually editing the scripts and fixing one error after another, but it's just digging me deeper.

Do I need to rollback on my desktop machine to the merge point, and then run a new

```
python manage.py db upgrade
```

I can't hack around it as the last thing I want is to have this same problem when I push to staging (which is currently behind the merge point).

If I do roll back on my desktop machine and the upgrade then fails again, where exactly will I stand?